# Determining location of relevant tnsnames.ora file

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, toad

I installed both the 32 and 64-bit Oracle 11g drivers. I search my PC looking for files with the name "tnsnames.ora" and found 3 in the following locations:

```
1. C:\Oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
2. C:\Oracle\product\11203_64bit\CLIENT_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
3. C:\Windows\TNS
```

The existence of the 3rd location of the tnsnames.ora file surprises me.

I have the following Oracle clients installed on my PC:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle 11.6\Toad.exe"
"C:\Program Files\Devart\dbForge Studio Express for Oracle\dbforgeoracle.exe"
```

Based on the location of each program (Program Files (x86) vs. c:\Program Files), This suggests to me that the Toad, a 32 bit program, should use the 32 bit driver and dbForge should use the 64 bit driver.

dbForge seems to use either the tnsnames.ora file in either location #2 or #3. I know this by systematically renaming all but one of the tns files and then checking to see if the connection names read from the file are available when trying to create a new connection from with the app.

However, TOAD seems to only recognize the tnsnames.ora file in location #3 and it did not recognize the tnsnames.ora file in location 2 at all! (Being that it was a 32 bit program, I did not expect it to recognize the tns file in location 2 and that was the case). TO summarize the TOAD test for the sake of hopeful clarity, TOAD only recognized the tns file in location 3.

Other colleagues do not have a tns file in location 3 on their machines. I'm not sure why I do. When I run Toad, it shows the following 2 Home, with the 32 bit Home as being the active one.

```
OraClient11g_home1 (11.2.0.3)
    ORACLE_HOME:C:\app\C39293\product\11.2.0\client_1
    ORACLE_HOME_NAME:OraClient11g_home1
    ORACLE_HOME_KEY:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
    ORACLE_SID:
    NLS_LANG:AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
    SQLPATH:
    LOCAL:
    Client DLL:C:\app\C39293\product\11.2.0\client_1\oci.dll
    TNSNames.ora:
    SQLNet.ora:
    LDAP.ora:
    Login.sql:
    GLogin.sql:
    In system PATH:No
    Home is valid:No
OraClient11g_home1_32bit (11.2.0.3)
    ORACLE_HOME:c:\oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1
    ORACLE_HOME_NAME:OraClient11g_home1_32bit
    ORACLE_HOME_KEY:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1_32bit
    ORACLE_SID:
    NLS_LANG:AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
    SQLPATH:c:\oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\dbs
    LOCAL:
    Client DLL:c:\oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\bin\oci.dll
    TNSNames.ora:
    SQLNet.ora:
    LDAP.ora:
    Login.sql:
    GLogin.sql:c:\oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql
    In system PATH:Yes
```

**Q1:** Is OraClient11g_home1 my 64 bit home or do I have two Oracle clients installed?

**Q2:** Why doesn't 32 bit TOAD use the tns in location #1 instead of only using the one in location #3?

**Q3:** If I leave on the tns file in location 3, both dbForge and TOAD work but I'd like to know why so I can accurately understand how to move tns info from one machine to another.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just based on your paths you have two installed clients as you suspect (Toad and dbforge are tools, not clients so your terminology is a bit off). One 32-bit, the other 64-bit. It appears that Toad is 32-bit based on its installation path, but execute it and go to Help|Support Bundle. You'll see the top header will be "APPLICATION INFORMATION (32-bit)" or "APPLICATION INFORMATION (64-bit)" just to confirm. Toad 11.6 was the first to introduce a 64-bit version.

Toad will only see the Oracle client that is for the same platform as it. So your 64-bit client is irrelevant for Toad's sake. The C:\Windows\TNS appears to be a folder used for TNS_ADMIN folder given its odd location and the fact that Toad sees it. At command prompt execute SET TNS_ADMIN and see if it reports "TNS_ADMIN=C:\Windows\TNS" If it does, then all Tools should be using that tnsnames.ora. That's a global override if you will that points to the folder containing your net configuration files. If you don't have TNS_ADMIN set as an environment variable then look for it in your Oracle root registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle.

If you use a common set of connections for all of your tools I'd delete all of your tnsnames.ora files. I'd also relocate that C:\Windows\TNS folder to somewhere more appropriate like C:\Oracle\Admin and create your tnsnames.ora, sqlnet.ora, and ldap.ora (if applicable) there. Create a TNS_ADMIN environment variable pointing to that location.

Comment: Actually, looks like you have three homes. Toad is finding two and it looks like you likely have a 64-bit installed as well.

Comment: Yes, when I open a cmnd window and type echo %TNS_ADMIN%, it displays C:\Windows\TNS. So, it appears as if I do have this environment variable that I previously was not aware of. That seems to be the missing bit of information that I needed. Thank you.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle` is for x64 Oracle Client. 32 bit Client searches in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Oracle`

Answer (score 17):

According Oracle these locations are searched for `tnsnames.ora`, resp. `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora`:

1. Oracle Net files in present working directory (PWD/CWD)
2. `TNS_ADMIN` defined sessionally or by user-defined script
3. `TNS_ADMIN` defined as a global environment variable
4. `TNS_ADMIN` defined in the registry
5. Oracle Net files in `%ORACLE_HOME/network|net80\admin` (Oracle default location)

However, I am not sure whether each application/driver follows this list. I got this list from Oracle [Document 111942.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=111942.1) referring to Oracle 9i, so it might be outdated.

In [Database Net Services Administrator's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/config_concepts.htm#NETAG003) the order is

1. `TNS_ADMIN` defined by environment variable
2. `TNS_ADMIN` defined in the registry (if `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable is not present)
3. `%ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin` directory (if `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable is not present)

I would recommend to define an environment variable for `TNS_ADMIN` and use only one tnsnames.ora file. In order to be on the safe side, check also your registry values.

If your files are **not** located in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`, I recommend to create a symbolic link for it - just to be on the *very* safe side, e.g. `mklink /d %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin c:\Oracle\common\settings\admin`

Another note, you don't have to "play" with your tnsnames.ora file. With [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Microsoft Sysinternals you can monitor each file access, i.e. the filter would be `Path contains tnsnames`

**Update**

When I run a test on my machine I get following order:

1. Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`
2. Registry Key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`
3. Registry Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`, resp. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`

   -> Only if `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable is not set.
4. `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`
5. Current directory (which can be different to directory where your application is located)
6. Folder where your application is located

**Update 2**

Obviously there is no fix search, it varies for different providers/drivers. Maybe it also depends on the Oracle version.

For example, the *Oracle HTTP Server* reads `TNS_ADMIN` setting from `opmn.xml` config file.

Another example, for ODP.NET Managed Driver (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) **beta** version, I found this order at [Oracle Managed and TNS Names](https://community.oracle.com/message/10610812#10610812) :

1. data source alias in the 'dataSources' section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.
4. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present at `%TNS_ADMIN%`
   (where `%TNS_ADMIN%` is an environment variable setting).
5. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present at `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`
   (where `%ORACLE_HOME%` is an environment variable setting).

In official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161) (12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4)) it says:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file (i.e. `machine.config`, `web.config`, `user.config`).
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

However, based on some tests I made with ODP.NET Managed Driver (4.121.2.0) it takes `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` and `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable into account. Locks like the documentation is not 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Visual Studio v2017 here is tnsNames File:

32 bits installation:

> c:\program files (x86)\oracle developer tools for
>   vs2017\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

64 bits installation:

> c:\program files\oracle developer tools for
>   vs2017\network\admin\tnsnames.ora