# Unable to connect with oracle database gettng error ORA-12154

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am using oracle client to connect with database and while opening connection getting below error.

Connection string present in tnsnameora.

Below is the code:

```
        string cs_OT = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CON_OT_DB"].ConnectionString;
        string cs_MEDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CON_ME_DB"].ConnectionString;

        OracleConnection Con_Pre_ot = new OracleConnection(cs_OT);
        OracleConnection Con_Pre_ME = new OracleConnection(cs_MEDB);


        Con_Pre_ME.Open();
        string Select_pk_id_row1 = "SELECT pk_id FROM (SELECT * FROM tss_ot_place_info ORDER BY pk_id desc) WHERE ROWNUM = 1";
        OracleCommand cmd_pk_id_r1 = new OracleCommand(Select_pk_id_row1, Con_Pre_ME);
        int pk_id_row1;
        pk_id_row1 = Convert.ToInt32(cmd_pk_id_r1.ExecuteScalar());
        //pk id for uk_tss_ot_place_info
        pk_id_row1_uk = pk_id_row1 + 1;
```

getting below error :
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

also would like to inform you that i am able to connect with sql developer.

Comment: Are you able to connect using the Oracle SQL developer tool with the same connection string?

Comment: Don't put screenshots in question. Write your code and error message as text.

Comment: Which provide do you use?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have use provider "Oracle.DataAccess.Client" rest I have paste code.Please advice.

Comment: Have a look at this answer and verify location of `tnsnames.ora` file.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit which answer are you talking about?

Comment: @RahulSingh, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924, sorry!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am still not able to get it resolve as it as the explanation given on the refer code having so many things to consider which I don't even know. Could you please let me any simple command query to check whether my connection are correct or not.

Comment: Can you connect with sql*plus?

Comment: I have tried to sql plus but it is asking for user id and name,am i suppose to mention user id and password for the database i wants to connect ??

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit One more thing i want to add up is that when i run command "tnsping oracle" is gives me a path parameter to sqlnet.ora file, not to the tnsname.ora file where all my connections reside.I have searched a lot how I can point it to right location but didn't get any relevant answer. It will be very helpful if you want help to assist me with this.

Comment: What is the value of `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable? What is the value in Registry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN` and/or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`? Where is your `tnsname.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` file located?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for TNS_ADMIN environment variable is "D:\app\singhra4\product\11.2.0\client_3\network\admin" and for registry, I can't see TNS_ADMIN there :(

Comment: Its showing OLEDB under Oracle key.

Comment: Having no entry in Registry is OK. Where are your files?

Comment: ... and show us the connection string

Comment: This error has resolved now but stuck with a different error now :( " Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019"