# Oracle ODBC: works from MS ODBC Admin(32) Test, but ORA-12154 from python

Tags: python, oracle, odbc

I am trying to connect from Windows Server 2008 R2 to remote Oracle 12.
I created tnsnames.ora

```
 
MY_DSN=
(DESCRIPTION=
   (ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=X.XXX.XX.XX)(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORASERVER))
)
```

I created System DSN using 32 bits ODBC Administrator.
There is "Test Connection" button in ODBC arministrator;  I used to confirm what connection works.

But I failed to use this DSN from python 3.4.3 Anaconda 2.2 (32 bits)

```
    import pypyodbc
    cStr = 'DSN=MY_DSN;UID=stranger;PWD=secret'
    conn = pypyodbc.connect(cStr)
```

I got

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08004', '[08004] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: 
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified\n')
```

Comment: can you add the dsn under the SYSTEM DSN tab.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924