# Oracle data tools for visual studio and tnsnames.orA

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, tnsnames

Just installed ODT, it wants tnsnames.ora, where should I put it?

Answer (score 1):

The default location is at `%ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin` but you can put it in any folder. Use environment variable (or Registry Key) `TNS_ADMIN` to specify the folder.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried!  Unfortunately the ODT install did not set that environment variable and the instructions didn't say anything about it. Should it have been added? BTW do you know where that registry key should go?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924