# ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm using the NuGet Package `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`. When calling `OracleConnection.Open();` I get the error named in the title. My Connection string looks like `Data Source=RAEDB;User ID=*****;Password=*****;`. In the `tnsnames.ora` this Data Source is configured like

```
RAEDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = OraDB_IHDB)(PORT = 1521))
     (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
    (CONNECT_DATA =      
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ihdb)
    )
  )
```

We don't use the `sqlnet.ora`, so the `tnsnames.ora` is used by default.

Weirdly this only happens in the NuGet Package version `12.2.1100`, but not in `12.1.24160419`. Might it be that version of the Package is faulty or is it some configuration I missed?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924 Apparently the search pattern for `tnsnames.ora` file depends on release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your `tnsnames.ora` stored? According [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8161) (12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4)) the search path is:

1. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

However, based on some tests I made with ODP.NET ManagedDriver (4.121.2.0) it takes also `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` and `TNS_ADMIN` Environment variable into account. Locks like the documentation is not 100% correct.

Note, unlike other drivers ODP.NET ManagedDriver does not read `TNS_ADMIN` value from your Registry!

Comment: I'm trying to use the `tnsnames.ora` in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`. So what you're saying is that the ODP.NET Managed Driver (4.122.2.0 (NuGet Package v12.2.1100)) does not use the `tnsnames.ora` in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` , but the Driver (4.121.2.0 (NuGet Package v12.1.24160419)) does?

Comment: I don't know. Documentation says it does not use `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`

Comment: Well it works for me now that I'm using the Driver version 4.121.2.0