# How do I list tnsnames

Tags: oracle, tnsnames, tnsping

Is there any **easy way** to list out all the available tnsnames in my system via command line?

Whenever I need to find out a tnsname, I just simply search for the **tnsnames.ora** file with **tnsping** command and open it in a text editor to scan through. Then subsequently run **tnsping [tnsname]** to check the connection health. I was thinking if there's any easy command like **tnslist or tns -l** to list out all the tnsnames but I couldn't find such.

Comment: Save all the SIDs, services in a single file once and loop through this file and do tnsping in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have such a `tnsnames.ora` file :

```
DB01 = 
    (DESCRIPTION = 
        (FAILOVER=off) 
        (LOAD_BALANCE=off) 
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db01-vip)(PORT = 1521)) 
         (CONNECT_DATA = 
             (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
             (SERVICE_NAME = mydb1) 
         ) 
     ) 

DB02 = 
    (DESCRIPTION = 
        (FAILOVER=off) 
        (LOAD_BALANCE=off) 
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db02-vip)(PORT = 1531)) 
         (CONNECT_DATA = 
             (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
             (SERVICE_NAME = mydb2) 
         ) 
     )
```

edit your .profile or .bash_profile like this:

> [oracle@mydb12c~ ] vi .bash_profile

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME
...
alias lstns="sed -n '/DESCR/{x;p;d;}; x' $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora | sed "s/=/${s}/""
echo 'lstns : tnsnames.ora listing'
```

> [oracle@mydb12c~ ] . .bash_profile

```
lstns : tnsnames.ora listing
```

> [oracle@mydb12c~ ] lstns

```
  DB01 
  DB02
```

Comment: Thanks much. We shall have similar .bat file in Windows as well and put it in the system path. So that, we shall run the command from terminal seamlessly. I initially thought there is a one bundle with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tnsnames.ora file listing command. But there are several options where the tnsnames.ora file can be placed. You can only use the find command
The priority of searching for tnsnames.ora files by the oracle client.

```
    1) current directory (Linux, Windows)
    2) $TNS_ADMIN (Linux, Windows environment variable, Windows registry key)
    3) $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin (Linux, Windows)
    4) /etc (Linux)
    5)  %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Oracle ( Windows 7). 


[root@elbrus-1 ~]#  find / -name tnsnames.ora
/opt/ora/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
/opt/ora/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/samples/tnsnames.ora
/home/oracle/diman/tnsnames.ora
[root@elbrus-1 ~]#
```

Comment: that isn't his question

Comment: @Dmitry Demin, Thanks for the reply but what I want to know is how to list tnsnames.

Comment: There is no tnsnames.ora file listing command.
But there are several options where the tnsnames.ora file can be placed. You can only use the find command.

Comment: I don't think `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Oracle` is any default directory for `tnsnames.ora` file. Most likely this is inherited from `TNS_ADMIN` setting. Do you have any reference for this list? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924 for more information.