# Test connection works, actual connection ends up with ORA-12154

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ssas

I'm trying to connect Microsoft SSAS with an Oracle database, with no success. I searched and searched before asking here, and I hoped the problem could lie in some typos in tnsnames.ora and sql.ora file. But unluckily not. I report them here:

**sqlnet**:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

**tnsnames**:

```
DEVELOPS.WORLD =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world)(PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = xxx.local)(Port = 1521))
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SID = DEVELOPS)
     )
   )
```

Note that, when I try "Test Connection" in SSAS, it does work. But as soon as process a table, for example, here comes ORA-12154.
I also tried with ping and tnsping, and they both work: host is up and running and the alias is working, too. Drivers (32bit and 64bit) are both installed. So, I really don't know what to look for.
Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to mention the database details you use in your client application.

Comment: How did you install Oracle drivers 32 bit and 64 bit? Compare with this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100 Perhaps the interfere with each other.

Comment: I didn't install the drivers, I'm working on a server set up by somebody else, so I found'em already in place. Directories seem to be ok. I'm adding this: from the very same SSAS, using the same tnsames/sql, I can connect to another server, load tabs etc. So the problem is just on one db (wth differente name and host obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely SSAS does find your `sqlnet.ora`, resp. `tnsnames.ora` file. Looks like each driver has its own method to look for location of these files, see [Determining locatation of relevant tnsnames.ora file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924)

Ensure that each setting listed below is pointing to actual location of your `sqlnet.ora`/`tnsnames.ora` files. Use [Symbolic Links](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx), if required.

- Environment varialbe `TNS_ADMIN`
- Registry Key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`
- Registry Key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{ORACLE_HOME_NAME}\TNS_ADMIN`
- Folder `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`
- `TNS_ADMIN` setting of section `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` in your .NET config file (only applicable for Oracle ODP.NET Managed Driver)