# I could not find a NETWORK\ADMIN folder in ORACLE installtion path

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed oracle 11g 64 bit version followed by 32 bit version.
I have heard that the TNS files will be in the folder structure - ...NETWORK\ADMIN folder in ORACLE installation path.

But there is no such folder created after oracle installation/

Comment: Then simply create the folder. TNS files can be located in different places see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: Or run `netca`, if you chose not to run it (or `dbca` )as part of the installation. [Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/rilin/oracle-net-services-configuration-files-and-parameters.html) about the network services files.

Comment: `tnsping` will print the path of its parameter files.

Comment: I got it resolved. While installation previously I selected - "Instant Client" option, now when I selected "Runtime" option and go ahead with installation, I got the required folder structure - ...NETWORK\ADMIN . Not sure why this question has been down voted.!

Answer (score 7):

Following @NidhinSPradeep suggestion I've reinstalled 12.2 client using Runtime option and it resolved the issue.

My machine had 12.1 32-bit Oracle client installed first at `C:\app\client\administrator\product\12.1.0\client_1`
and 12.2 64-bit installed second at `C:\app\client\%UserName%\product\12.2.0\client_1`

12.2 was installed as InstantClient type and `NETWORK\ADMIN` folder was missing for this installation.

This generated following error while using OraClient12Home1(64bit) in Toad Data Point:
`[Oracle Database Error] Server did not respond within the specified timeout interval`

I've reinstalled 12.2 client using Runtime option. `NETWORK\ADMIN` folder appeared and Toad Data Point error got resolved. If you reinstalling same version, change location from suggested (`client_2`) to whatever your existing location. Generally it is `client_1`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your `ORACLE_HOME` if correctly points to the given directory in the system variables. It may be sometimes Oracle would not be able to find the mentioned `ORACLE_HOME` directory.

Other probable reason would be the directory permissions. Make sure that all directories and subdirectories have proper permissions for the user from which Oracle is being installed.

Hope that helps :)