# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified - WHY?

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I have a .net app with a oracle database, I have not changed any config file or the tnsnames.ora ,and suddenly get this error.

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I try a lot of time to think, what can it be?Does anything have an idea?

Comment: Please do a `tnsping<servicename>` and see the output.

Comment: include the ora-xxx error code

Comment: Most likely your application does not find the `tnsnames.ora` file. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: check your $TNS_ADMIN variable, this point to tnsnames.ora location. In case not set, it goes to default of $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Comment: @FábioGalera, `$TNS_ADMIN` and `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` looks like Linux but problem is on .NET, so most likely Windows. The search path for `tnsnames.ora` can vary a lot.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The idea of TNS_ADMIN and ORACLE_HOME/network/admin is the same for Windows and Linux, you just have to change the variable from $ to %%

Comment: @FábioGalera, I mean on Windows the application searches also other loacation, e.g. defined by Registry key or current folder or defined in .NET config file.