# Issue when trying to connect to Oracle DB in C#

Tags: c#, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to connect to an Oracle DB using the following method:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "User ID=ID;Password=PASSWORD;Data Source=SOURCE";
con.Open();
write("connected to oracle " + con.ServerVersion);
```

But every time I run the program I get the error:

> [2018-11-01 09:29:19.705] System.BadImageFormatException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBLIC_KEY' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format. File name: 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBLIC_KEY'    at
>   adrentech_previous_day.Program.processFile()    at
>   adrentech_previous_day.Program.Main() in
>   DIRECTORY\program:line
>   25
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=PUBLIC_KEY  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///DIRECTORY
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly :
>   adrentech_previous_day, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   DIRECTORY\program.vshost.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration
>   file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBLIC_KEY LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///DIRECTORY/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing
>   terminated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) You can use the [Oracle Managed client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/), which has no external dependencies and isn't X86/64 specific. 2) Make sure you wrap your [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects such as OracleConnection in a using statement.

Comment: I installed the Oracle Managed client and wrapped the OracleConnection in a using statement, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you make sure to remove the referenced to the non managed client?

Comment: Okay yes I just did that, now I am getting a new error: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00002F7A): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: That's good, that means you got further. I suggest you use a connection string such as this: `SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: Is "MyHost" = the database? And how would I find "MyOracleSID"? Also does the port number have to change?

Comment: MyHost is the database server DNS name or IP address. MyOracleSID is usually the name of your database. The default port for Oracle is 1521. If you're hosting it on a different port, then you'll need to change it to that port.

Comment: Okay after a lot of digging I was able to get all the information, but now I'm getting this error: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Try to use the TNS alias (see my answer below) rather than the full connection string. Also I think instead of `SERVER=...` it must be `Data Source=...`

Comment: I have the TNSNAMES.ORA file, what directory should that go in inside my program directory? Also how to I reference the document which an alias connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your compile target is .NET Framework 4.0 (or higher) but you installed the ODP.NET version 2.x - they don't work together.

One solution is to use the ODP.NET Managed Driver - which you did already. However, there is also anther solution, see [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992)

Now the second problem regarding `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

ODP.NET Managed Driver uses a different method to find the `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` (and `ldap.ora`, if used) files than the unmanaged driver, see [Determining location of relevant tnsnames.ora file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924)

The unmanaged drivers searches folder `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` and reads Registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1\TNS_ADMIN`, the ODP.NET Managed Driver does not.

The ODP.NET Managed Driver retrieves location of `tnsnames.ora` from your .NET config file, i.e. `machine.config`. You can modify the file manually (see [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm)) or use a batch script as below (pick x64 or x86 lines which are relevant for you and change folder names according to your machine)

```
set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\11.2\Client_x64\odp.net
set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\11.2\Client_x86\odp.net

OraProvCfg_x64=%Oracle_x64%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe
OraProvCfg_x86=%Oracle_x86%\bin\4\OraProvCfg.exe

set TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\network\admin

"%OraProvCfg_x64%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
"%OraProvCfg_x86%" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
```

Or set `TNS_ADMIN` as Environment variable which should work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I set the path to the directory with the files tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora in the TNS_ADMIN computer variable and it worked for me without rebooting.