# Connect to Oracle DB via ODBC driver

Tags: oracle, powerbi

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle Database via ODBC. 
This connection will allow me to connect Power BI Desktop to Oracle.
Using SQL Developer, I can managed to establish the connection, see the tables, views, etc.

Now, using Oracle Client `64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64`, I get this `tnsnames.ora` file with the following configurations:

```
MYCONNECT=
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 123.xxxx.xxx..xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL) 
    )
  )
```

This all looks ok, but when trying to create the ODBC driver in windows, I get the following after entering the credentials:

[image]

And the error:

[image]

So, why can I establish the connection via SQL developer and not via ODBC driver?

And how can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: is this a matter that you connecting using wrong ODBC, 32bit vs 64bit. You probably just not pointing to right place somewhere

Comment: Perhaps this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: As far as I know (but I am not sure), SQL developer does not use the `tnsnames.ora` file - and the ODBC driver does not find it.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sql Developer has multiple modes of connection.

Comment: @T.S. I'm using 64-bit because my system is 64bit. How can I check where to find what is connecting to what?

Comment: Where is your `tnsnames.ora` file located? Did you set `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable or did you set `TNS_ADMIN` in your Registry?

Comment: *"I'm using 64-bit because my system is 64bit."* - but does sql developer use x64?. Plus, I generally not sure what is going on. If you use TNS then why do you need ODBC?  It is one or another. You can put SID and all in Sql devaloper directly, without TNS

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit my tnsnames.ora file is in my D drive, I can't anwser your second question, I have no idea what TNS_ADMIN is. I'm just trying to connect Power BI to Oracle, like I have done with SQL Server DB, Access, MySQL DB, and a constellation of web API. But with ORACLE!? Too F***CKING complicated! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @T.S.All I'm trying to do is to connect Power BI Desktop to an Oracle DB, but it seems like mission impossible. It's been 2 weeks now and I'm getting crazy. I'm just following the explanation as per this post: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Connect-To-Oracle-Database/td-p/188217

Comment: What I see from your link, is that ODBC DSN was used only to test connection. But you can do it using `tnsping` (although, this is partial test - only tests that service name is connected). And then, what you put as TNS name (in your case `MYCONNECT`) will be going into field `Server`. If you installed Ora client, `tnsnamemes.ora` should be under folder `network/admin`

Comment: Thanks, tsnames.ora is in \product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin

Comment: so, somewhere in your `\product\12.1.0\client_1` you have `tnsping.exe`. Open CMD window, type or paste full path and tns name `c:\....\product\12.1.0\client_1\....\tnsping.exe MYCONNECT`. It should give you `OK`. If not `OK`, you have issue in your TNS or DB server

Comment: @NunoNogueira, come on - you should know what an "environment variable" is and how to set it. If you don't know, use google.

Comment: Please show us what you put in ODBC Driver Configuration, i.e. Data Source Name, TNS Service Name, etc.