# Connecting to Oracle, Managed Data Acces via tnsnames.ora

Tags: .net, oracle, data-access-layer, tnsnames, oracle-manageddataaccess

Actually the solution we have works with an obsolete unmanaged(?) Oracle .NET provider `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`, and it uses the computer's `tnsnames.ora` file.

We would like to update that and use instead the Oracle managed dll (via latest version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess nuget).

We have in the application `web.config` a key that indicates what `tnsnames` source to use.

What is obscure a little bit to me, what changes actually there is to do after the installation of the managed nuget and removing of the old `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`...

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider the unmanaged ODP.NET as obsolete. It is still developed and maintained, currently you can download version 19. Apart from determining location of `tnsnames.ora` file there is nothing to to. Removing the unmanaged ODP.NET is optional.

Note, the search pattern for `tnsnames.ora` file is different in Managed ODP.NET than it was for the unmanaged provider, see [Determining location of relevant tnsnames.ora file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924)

One important difference is: The Managed driver does **not** read the Registry for `TNS_ADMIN` whereas the unmanaged driver does.