# How does Oracle.ManagedDataAccess handle tnsname.ora in version 19.3?

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess, oracle.manageddataaccess

With `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` `12` and `18`, if you want to use `tnsname.ora` aliases, then you have to define the Environment Variable `TNS_ADMIN` with the corresponding path.

I just discovered that the version `19` is able to get the `tnsname.ora` configuration without this Environment Variable but I'm not sure how?

Neither the `web.cong` nor the `machine.config` contains that Environment Variable.

There seems to be a path in Registry Editor but my project still works when I modify the path with erroneous one.

[image]

From what I have tested, here is a list of what works and what doesn't :

- Local client `19.3` with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess `19.3` (and superior) : Works without `TNS_ADMIN` Env
- Local client `19.3` with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess `18.6` (and prior) : Doesn't work without `TNS_ADMIN` Env
- Local client `12.1` with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (all versions) : Doesn't work without `TNS_ADMIN` Env

So i'm wondering why does this particular case work?

Also is there a method inside Oracle.ManagedDataAccess that return the used `tnsname.ora` path?

Thanks,

Comment: I know earlier versions of ODP.NET Managed driver did not read the registry at all. Run [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and check what is actually read by the application.

Comment: Value of `TNS_ADMIN` might be taken from cache. Ensure you reboot the computer between the tests.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924 - resolution for `tnsnames.ora` file seems to be volatile in ODP.NET Managed driver.

Comment: Thx for your answers, the Process Monitor option really helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers.

I finally found the solution using Process Monitor (thx @WernfriedDomscheit) and filtering the `Path` column with `TNS_ADMIN`.

There are two paths in the Registry Editor that contain the `TNS_ADMIN`variable:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET.Managed\4.122.19.1
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE\ODP.NET.Managed\4.122.19.1

I was only trying to remove the non-`WOW6432Node` path. If I also remove the `WOW6432Node` one, then `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` successfully fail.

Comment: It depends on your compile settings. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` is used when your application runs in 64-bit mode, whereas `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE` is used by applications running in 32-bit mode. See [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from more details.

Comment: Optionally you could also have `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET.Managed\4.122.19.1` key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience specifically with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, but I do know that in general, *no* client *requires* TNS_ADMIN to be set. The TNS layer itself has an order of precedence where it looks to find tnsnames.ora, and this is outside of the calling client. First it looks for a TNS_ADMIN environment variable. If that is not set, or tnsnames.ora is not found where TNS_ADMIN points, it next checks the process's current directory. If not found there, it checks $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin.  I'd say your statement "if you want to use tnsname.ora aliases, then you have to define the Environment Variable TNS_ADMIN with the corresponding path" is a conclusion you came to based on incorrect interpretation of either reading or observation.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. You are right, my statement is a bit excessive. But what I meant was that if nothing is found by the client, then the easiest solution is to set the TNS_ADMIN env variable. By default the oracle install does not set anything for he ManagedDataAccess library, you should run configuraiton scripts by yourself, so in general the proposed solution is to set the TNS_ADMIN at the project level so you cannot have side effects on your install. (here again, like you said, it is a personal conclusion, maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: OK, so, as I said, the process of locating tnsnames.ora (as well as sqlnet.ora) occurs after the client has passed the request to the TNS layer, and there it has at least two places it will look if TNS_ADMIN is not set at the OS process level. So that is why "version 19 is able to get the tnsname.ora configuration without this Environment Variable"

Comment: Ok. I realize my mistake after finding the solution. I was pretty sure none of those variables you mentioned were set, but I was not looking on the correct registry key. Thx again.