# Set up ODBC connection for Oracle

Tags: oracle, odbc

ALL,

How do I properly set up an ODBC connection to Oracle DB?

I did install everything that is needed. I ran the installer and when I start the ODBC manager I do see Oracle driver installed.

Now when I start the setup dialog it has a field for `TNS Service name`. It is a combo box and when I pull it down - it is empty.
Should I fill it with a value of the IP address (something like 127.0.0.1:1521@X@), where 1521 is a default port and XE is the default DB name from tnsnames.ora?

Or the field should be just `XE`?

Or something else?

Please help.

TIA!

Comment: Are you using the Oracle ODBC driver (implying that you installed the Oracle client already)?  Have you configured a TNS entry (commonly in the tnsnames.ora file but there are other methods of TNS name resolution)?

Comment: @JustinCave, yes, I'm on Windows (10). And I am using native Oracle ODBC driver along with the client basic packet. And no - I didn't do anything else. How do I configure it? I did open the `tnsnames.ora` file. Also, I can successfully connect using SQLPlus, using `connect system/<password>@XE`, where `XE` comers from that file. So I just thought that this will work for ODBC.

Comment: You should also check the environment variables `ORACLE_HOME` or `TNS_ADMIN` which is used for `tnsnames.ora` path resolution. Also check if the installed ODBC driver and the software which you use for setup have the same architecture. Maybe you use 32 bit client for 64 bit application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either ways, i.e. the alias from `tnsnames.ora` file (or other name resolution methods) `XE` or the full string `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)))`

I don't know whether ODBC supports EZ-Connect, `127.0.0.1:1521@XE@`, but you can try.

When the drop down list is empty, then most likely the ODBC driver does not find your `tnsnames.ora` file, see [Determining location of relevant tnsnames.ora file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924)

Comment: so IIUC, I should add the path to tnssames.ora to the PATH env variable and then the combo will be populated right?

Comment: No, when you read linked answer then you see `PATH` environment variable is not mentioned at all. Define environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` with the folder name.