# How to find Host from ODBC DSN?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odbc

I have a System DSN ( name =**appdsn**) configured in ODBC DataSources 64 Bit in Windows 10.

This connects to an Oracle database 11g.

I could not locate the responsible tnsnames. ora to this DSN.

Is there any way to locate with the help of DSN name?

Comment: The tnsnames.ora is simply a text file.  The best way to locate it is to use the OS's file search feature.  I'm going to presume you are on Windows.  Open Windows Explorer.  In the upper-right corner is a search field.  Enter 'tnsnames.ora' and execute the search.  I suspect you are asking this question to solve some other problem, but if you asked about that other problem, you'd get better help, faster.

Comment: If you want to extract a DSN's attributes from within a Python script on Windows you can use my [dump_dsn](https://github.com/gordthompson/dump_dsn) utility.

Comment: tnsnames.ora is searched for in `%TNS_ADMIN%` or `%ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin` directories in this priority. Here's the [description](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/tnsnames.htm#NETRF259)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28283924/3027266