# Program connects to Oracle database using System.Data.OracleClient but can't find tnsnames

Tags: c#, oracle, system.data.oracleclient

I have a WinForms program that connects to an Oracle database server using deprecated System.Data.OracleClient. When I try installing that program on another computer, this program is trying to use SID's from that is defined in the `tnsnames.ora` file, but can't find the file.

Where do I put the `tnsnames.ora` file so that it is visible to the program?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Answer (score 0):

If you have the oracle client installed, use the tnsping command from a cmd promt. the path of tnsname file will appear