# UDL connection with Oracle database using OLEDB Provider

Tags: oracle, oledb, sqlplus

I am trying to connect the oracle database using universal data link(UDL) with the provider as "Oracle provider for OLEDB"

The test connection fails with the below error

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

I am able to connect to the oracle database using SQLPLUS and Oracle SQL Developer from the same machine.

[image]

Please suggest the possible root cause of the issue.

Comment: try wf49 as your data source

Comment: @Ciarán Already I'm using wf49 in my data source. Here is the value of my data source 10.96.198.49/wf49

Comment: Where did you get _10.96.198.49_ from? Maybe try 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Comment: 10.96.198.49 is a remote database server IP. I can access the same DB server using SQL developer and SQLPLUS utility

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: wf49 is configured in your tnsnames file. You don't specify the ip address when using sqlplus nor should you need it here. I've never used udl file but I've used oracle extensively. You can also try using the (DESCRIPTION=....) entry from the tnsnames.

Comment: What's your Provider?

Comment: Wf49 is configured in TNS entry. Also i can access the SQLPLUS using the IP address successfully. The UDL is using "Oracle Provider for OLE DB" as the Provider

Comment: Connection is Working when we use only the wf49(Instance name)