# I am trying to connect to Oracle through Visual Studio and II have no idea whats wrong, even tho connection in Sql developer is working normally

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio, oracle-sqldeveloper

Visual keeps giving me a TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified error when I try to establish a connection with an Oracle db even tho I can successfully connect on SQL developer

Comment: Can you ping the server? Is the port# correct? Are you specifying a SID or Service Name?

Comment: See following : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG357

Comment: What 'type' of connection did you specify in SQL Dev?  My guess is in SQL Dev you specified 'basic' connection type, which does not use the tnsnames to resolve the reference. Your reported error (which is an ora-12154, BTW - it would be better for you to include the actual error code) indicates your specified database reference is not found in the tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924 SQL Developer is Java/JDBC based, the name resolution works different than in .NET application.