# How do we know that oracle client is instantclient or not?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, node-oracledb

sqlnet.ora configurations in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin is not being considered. I came to know that instant client version of oracle doesn't take that configuration. I want to know whether my oracle client is instant client or not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: The Instant Client directory has its own network/admin subdirectory (in older versions you can manually create this; in newer versions it is precreated).  We strongly recommend not setting ORACLE_HOME when using Instant Client libraries.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to stop the instantclient to use sqlnet.ora/tnsnames.ora, it just doesn't use them by default. For example, if I set TNS_ADMIN then it will happily use the standard tnsnames entries

```
C:\oracle\instantclient>set TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\product\19\network\admin\

C:\oracle\instantclient>sqlplus demo/demo@db19_pdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Jul 29 13:47:39 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sat Jul 10 2021 08:55:10 +08:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

If that variable is not set, then you can use the EZCONNECT syntax (which also applies to the standard client), so there isn't really a great deal of the difference between the two to worry about.

Perhaps a bigger area on interest is the different between thin and thick driver, but even then, this is mainly in the types of HA and failover options.