# listener.ora, tnsnames.ora & sqlnet.ora not in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Tags: oracle

I'm currently exploring the Oracle Database 21c but I just realised that my listener.ora, tnsnames.ora & sqlnet.ora is not in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin by default.

I'm running Oracle Linux 7 on docker and this is my output

```
[oracle@d62a3728924b scripts]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 15-OCT-2021 18:14:54

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                15-OCT-2021 18:06:27
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 8 min. 26 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/homes/OraDB21Home1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/d62a3728924b/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=d62a3728924b)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

My $ORACLE_HOME is in a different location

```
[oracle@d62a3728924b scripts]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/u01/app/oracle/product/21.0.0/dbhome_1
```

How can I change the Listener Parameter File to point to $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin?

Comment: Sounds like you have $TNS_ADMIN set.  Read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntqrf/about-tns-admin-parameter.html#GUID-7EE1F936-F108-4575-941C-63E0011B0CC0).   As for _"Listener Parameter File to point to $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin"_, it is illogical to change a parameter file to tell oracle to find it somewhere else.  By the time oracle has located a copy and read it, it is already too late to find it somewhere else. Like "When I'm looking for something, it's always in the last place I look."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Answer (score 0):

This is a 21c new feature.

This is not a change you can do ,
Oracle 21c has a new feature to have the tnsnames.ora in a home folder

/u01/app/oracle/homes/<<home_name>>/network/admin

Please refer the documentation below.

Section : File Path and Directory Changes in Read-Only Oracle Homes

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/ladbi/file-path-directory-changes-read-only-oracle-home.html#GUID-695D5458-A4AF-4F2A-AE4B-FB1062CF6014