# Oracle DB connection issue through external connection

Tags: windows, oracle, database-design, oracle19c

Need your advise on the below:

Recently we migrated to Oracle client 19c from Oracle 11g through script on the windows server.

The script has wiped the previous Environment variable path for oracle 11g and replaced with 19c which is good.

The set up is such that, When I tried to connect to the DB, it first checks the environmental variable and then establishes the DB connection.

```
Sample Script:
set ora
set tns
pause
tnsping GENPF_dev_connect
sqlplus
```

The respective output are

```
"set ora"
ORACLE_Home=F:\GENPF\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_32

Note: This path is correctly set
```

```
"set tns"
TNS_ADMIN=C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\Client_1\Network\Admin\
TNS_NAMES=F:\GENPF\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_32\network\admin

Note: Not sure from where Oracle took the TNS_ADMIN path.
      TNS_NAMES path is correctly set
```

```
tnsping GENPF_dev_connect

Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\Client_1\Network\Admin\sqlnet.ora
```

The strange part on tnsping is, even after defining and retrieving the right TNS_NAMES, it only checks the path for TNS_ADMIN.

As a work around, I set the TNS_ADMIN with the right path under Environmental variable such as

```
TNS_ADMIN=F:\GENPF\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_32\network\admin
```

Even after adding the above entry, Oracle seems to ignore the environment variable path added and always provides the old entry.

Please suggest where things are going wrong on this?

Comment: `TNS_NAMES` is not correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for your comment.
```
From the ORACLE_HOME path available, the TNS_NAMES seems to be correct.(from my little brain..please point out how is it not the right path. Checked the given link, still not able to figure it out)

```
ORACLE_Home=F:\GENPF\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_32
      TNS_NAMES=F:\GENPF\Oracle\product\19.0.0\client_32\network\admin
```

Comment: TNS_NAMES isn't something used by Oracle anywhere. I think you've got confused by the `tns_admin` environment being the directory where it should first look for the `tnsnames.ora`. Fix your `tns_admin` variable (or don't set it at all, the standard installation will take care of it for you via the registry)

Comment: @Andrew Sayer. Thanks.

I am trying to remove the TNS_ADMIN, but not sure where to remove this entry ? If it is available under environmental variable, I would have removed it easily. What is the alternate area to check for the TNS_ADMIN.

Comment: Read my linked answer, it's all explained there.