# ORACLE_HOME Environment Variable vs Registry

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework

This is more of a question to help sharpen my understanding of behind the scenes Oracle magic than anything else.

I have been having some TNS issues lately when trying to serve a .NET REST API that uses EF with an Oracle .Net Provider. When I hit an endpoint, I received the exception 'ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified'. After fiddling with VS Oracle provider settings, registry values, and environment variables (and several reinstalls), I found that adding ORACLE_HOME as a value to environment variables made this error go away.

My question is, if I have the same exact ORACLE_HOME value in the Oracle key in my registry, why does it throw an error if I remove the environment variable? Does this mean there is something screwy with my registry setup? I do not recall needing to have ORACLE_HOME environment variable in the past.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-locatation-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924

Comment: Indeed, in [Multiple Oracle Homes and Optimal Flexible Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a95490/orahome.htm#1006117) it says: "*Oracle Corporation recommends that you never set the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable, because it is not required for Oracle products to function properly. If you set the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable, then Oracle Universal Installer will unset it for you.*" However, this is **Oracle version 9.2**! I don't find such statement for any current release, so maybe it has been changed.