# Oracle.ManagedDataAcess.Client how to connect using TNSNAMES when there are two definitions of alias - first is with FAILOVER

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames, oracle.manageddataaccess

I want to connect using alias from tnsnames.ora.
I parse the file selected based on environment and registry configuration.
I don't know diferent way to connect by alias.
I am currently facing an issue with one of my client becouse he has strange configuration in tnsnames. He has defined two aliases with the same name in the configuration file, with one of them specifying FAILOVER_MODE.
Trick is with tnsping.exe that returns proper connectionstring.

Definition of tnsnames.ora - notice that aliases are the same, but tnsping for alias tns_1 returns second connection string.

```
tns_1 = 
    (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.2)(PORT=1521)))
    (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVER=DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME=orcl)
        (FAILOVER_MODE =
                (TYPE=SESSION)
                (METHOD=BASIC)
                (RETRIES=250)
                (DELAY=3)
        )
    )
)
 
tns_1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.local)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

How can I obtain the correct connection string for connecting to a database using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess? I prefer not to use tnsping because not all clients have it installed on their machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "I don't know different way to connect by alias"?

With the ODP.NET Managed Driver you can simply use the alias. Be, aware the ODP.NET Managed Driver does not read the Windows Registry to determine the location of your `tnsnames.ora` file, see [Determining location of relevant tnsnames.ora file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924)

For the ODP.NET Managed Driver, you can specify the location also similar to this:

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%
ODP.NET\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:ODP.NET\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:C:\oracle\network\admin
ODP.NET\managed\x86\OraProvCfg.exe /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:ODP.NET\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:C:\oracle\network\admin
```

You should not have the same alias multiple times in your `tnsnames.ora`, the result is not determined. As software developer, I would even raise an error.

Comment: Question rather is why tnsping.exe returns the correct datasource. Other programs also can connect by alias. I don't know how to connect by alias using this tnsnames.
I have reviewed the post you mentioned. Your examination of the location of tnsnames looks similar to mine. I parse the tnsname and choose the first connection string that is incorrect for connection. How should I determine this location to connect by aliast using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess  ?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Why do consider the second entry as correct and not the first? As said, the result is not determined, tnsping returns the "correct" resolution just by coincidence.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, just use the alias, i.e. `"Data Source=tns_1;User ID=...;Password=..."`. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess should find the `tnsnames.ora` and resolve the alias automatically.

Comment: "just use the alias"
But You mentioned ealier that "Be, aware the ODP.NET Managed Driver does not read the Windows Registry " ? What did you mean by that?

Comment: Read the linked answer. Question: How does Oracle.ManagedDataAccess find your `tnsnames.ora` file? Short answer: It searches the `TNS_ADMIN` (environment variable) folder, then the folder specified in your .NET `.config` file and then the folder where your application `.exe` is stored. However, unlike `tnsping` and many other drivers, the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess does not check your Registry. So, verify `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable and the .NET config file.

Comment: Exacly. So If I understand you correctly, to connect by Oracle.ManagedDataAccess I should look for tnsname throught registry , parse the file and get the datasource string by myself. Now, my question is, why other programs seems work fine. I believe they somehow obtaining the second datasource string. Is there a way to check if the datasource string is correct. Perhaps this is verified by other drivers ?

Comment: I would suggests to read the `TNS_ADMIN` value from Registry (apparently it is set only in your Registry) and define this value also as the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable, then it will just work. And/or set the value in your .config file.

Comment: InstantClient not supported. I am now struggling with this kind of settings on my client machine.

Comment: The ODP.NET Managed driver is a stand-alone driver, i.e. it does not use any other Oracle client libraries. Thus such error messages does not make much sense.